# implement java function in c#

Tags: c#, java, .net

I have this generi interface and class in written in Java

```
public abstract class MyRootAbstractClass<W>
{
}

public abstract class MyDerivedAbstractClass<W extends MyRootFatherClass>
{
}
```

Notice `:MyRootFatherClass` (in MyDeriveAbstractClass declaration) doesn't asks for generic type (`<W>`).

Is any one knows How can i convert this code to C#???

Comment: Actually, you only have two generic abstract classes...

Answer (score 5):

Looks to me like:

```
public abstract class MyRootAbstractClass<T>
{
}

public abstract class MyDerivedAbstractClass<T> where T : MyRootFatherClass
{
}
```

The `where T : MyRootFatherClass` is a generic type constraint so that you can't create a `MyDerivedAbstractClass<T>` for arbitrary `T` types - only `MyRootFatherClass` and subclasses.

Note that I've renamed `W` to `T` in order to follow .NET naming conventions.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a [generic constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

```
public abstract class MyRootAbstractClass<W>
{
}

public abstract class MyDerivedAbstractClass<W> where W : MyRootFatherClass
{
}
```

Comment: It doesn't compile, It demands to insert a generic type when implementing MyRootFatherClass (For example :MyRootFatherClass<M>)

Comment: Example Edit : public abstract class MyDerivedAbstractClass<W> where W : MyRootFatherClass <M> .JAVA doesn't demand to declare on generic type when declaring generic class (MyRootFatherClass) as constraint.